# DialogFragment as inner class inside a Fragment ( Support Library Fragment v4)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two fragments `Fragment A` and `Fragment B`,both fragments have defined `interfaces` for communication and  `ActivityMain` has implemented both interfaces.

Sample Code for `Fragment A`

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment
{
    public interface myInterface
      {
         doSomethingFromFragmentA();
      }
   private myInterface listener;
   @Override OnAttach(Context activity)
     {
        listener=(myInterface) activity;
     }
}
```

Sample Code for `Fragment B`

```
    public class FragmentA extends Fragment
    {
        public interface myInterfaceforB
          {
             doSomethingFromFragmentB();
          }
       private myInterfaceforB listener;
       @Override OnAttach(Context activity)
         {
            listener=(myInterfaceforB) activity;
         }

      private DialogFragment dialog=new DialogFragment()
        {
          @Override
             public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle)
                {
                   //in this dialog creating a AlertDialog and calling doSomethingFromFragmentB() from dialog ok button
                }

        }
```

I have shown sample code of both `Fragments` , you people should assume I have implemented interfaces in `ActivityMain`.

You have noticed I have a `innerclass` in `FragmentB` which is another type of `fragment`. In `DialogFragment`'s OK button I was trying to call `FragmentB` interface method on `ActivityMain.`
I have two problems:

1st:`DialogFragment` is inside `FragmentB`,so `FragmentB` is its parent,not `ActivityMain`. Calling interface implemented method from this kind of Inner `DialogFragment`? how this works conceptually in communication to host `Activity`(Grand parent in this case)

2nd: its also giving me error that inner fragments should be static because of some fragment retain problem, but when I make it static then I also have to make listener variable static becase im using listener variable inside this DialogFragment. but it still gives me below error

> Fragment null must be a public static class to be properly recreated
>   from instance state

Answer (score -1):

Implement your Own DialogFrament and ask your implementation constructor to have a callback which will trigger in your fragment.

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment{

MyInterface mi;

    MyDialog(MyInterface mi){
    this.mi = mi;
    }

    // on some action mi.yourCallBack();
    }
```

So when you initialize your dialog fragment pass an interface to it and you will recieve a callback on your action to your fragment.

Comment: and answer for my 1st problem?

Comment: it is not reccomended to use a non-default constructor in fragments